# Replace a character in middle of characters using regular expression in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

These are the variable names in a C code its been used in like 100 files i need to replace it by small cases as shown below in a folder having like 100 files 
any one please help me out how to do it with regular expressions

I have a set of variable names like the following:

```
Cell_01_Voltage
Cell_02_Voltage
Cell_03_Voltage
Cell_04_Voltage

.
.
.
.
.
Cell_99_Voltage
```

I want final the text as this:

```
cell_01_voltage
cell_02_voltage
cell_03_voltage
cell_04_voltage
.
.
.
.
.
cell_99_voltage
```

How to achieve this using notepad++ ?

Comment: maybe regex can't. or if it could it'd be some very 'advanced' feature supported only in perl, notice answers don't involve regex

Comment: @Jagadish: Pick one Stack Exchange user ID, register it, and delete the other.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do a Find and Replace for `Cell` to `cell` and a second from `Voltage` to `voltage` if these variables are sprinkled about your code. If there are other instances of `Cell` or `Voltage` in your code that you don't wish to convert to lowercase you could `CTRL+H` for Find and replace, select `Regex` at the bottom and use `(Cell_.._Voltage)` for the "FindWhat" and `\L\1` for the "Replace With"

Answer (score 2):

Is that simply uppercase to lowercase... If so just select all text > right click > lowercase...

Answer (score 2):

Select the text you want to update and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. This will convert capital letters to lower case.